# vb excel replace part of a word in a cell loop

Tags: vba, excel

been working with Visual Basic for Excel and have been trying to loop through a huge column of cells and replace part of the cells with an input that i saved to a variable in the code.

For example:

```
123 
ip address [ip_address]  255.255.255.255
345
678
```

I need to replace the [ip_address] in every cell that it repeats in with the ip address that I input through a userform. The way ive done it so far is I do it manually for each cell and inputting the rest of the constants as strings but I know it can probably be done easier with a sort of loop. Ive tried recording macros and etc Idk if theres another way to do it that might be better than inputing a value into a cell and then copying that value into a variable but thats what I know how to do! Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on any cell in the column and run this:

```
Sub IPFixer()
    Dim BigR As Range, Stuff As String, OldStuff As String
    Set BigR = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection.EntireColumn).Cells
    Stuff = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter string", Type:=2)
    OldStuff = "[ip_address]"
    BigR.Replace What:=OldStuff, Replacement:=Stuff
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible to set BigR as column A of my new sheet? Because thats the only columm that will ever be changed like that. Also random question i already have an input that sets a cell to a value. Is that value going to be a string value automatically? Or do I convert it to a string and then input it as my "Stuff" String ?

Comment: The answer to your questions is **Yes**  You would modify my sample code to achieve you specific goals.

Comment: Cool I got the idea now. Thank you!